# Meaning of this code : is_noun = lambda pos: pos[:2] == 'NN'

Tags: python, dataframe, neural-network

Here is my code [Link] (https://www.kaggle.com/fabiendaniel/customer-segmentation) Part 3.1 Product Descriptions

Doing NLP , came across this code, precisly looking for 'pos' part, what does it do?

```
is_noun = lambda pos: pos[:2] == 'NN'
```

Comment: pos is `possible_noun` i guess ... (poorly named)... its just checking if it startswith "NN"

Comment: please include more information about the library used so that everyone can take a look and the code and respond properly.

Comment: `pos` is merely the first (and only) argument to that function. Note, this is bad style, if you are going to assign the result of a `lambda` expression to a variable, you might as well use a normal function definition

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using `nltk`. The function `is_noun` tests to see... well whether its input is a noun.

Here are the noun codes for part of speech tags in NLTK (from [here](https://pythonprogramming.net/part-of-speech-tagging-nltk-tutorial/)):

```
NN:   noun, singular 'desk'
NNS:  noun plural   'desks'
NNP:  proper noun, singular 'Harrison'
NNPS: proper noun, plural   'Americans'
```